# Texture Paint not working correctly, object turning invisible

Tags: texture-painting

I want to Texture Paint, but everywhere I paint the mesh turns invisible. Its like my brush is an "Invisible" Brush and wherever I paint instead of painted color the object disappears, like if I paint a heart there is a heart shaped hole in the object.

I don't know what to do because I think I have done everything corrrectly. I have UV unwrapped and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the top menu of the *Texture Paint* window if you have set the *Brush blending mode* to *Erase Alpha*. In this mode, the *Alpha* channel gets painted black so that these parts become transparent:

[image: erase alpha]

Comment: I have set it to "Mix" but have the problem

Comment: I made a screen record showing my problem ... maybe that helps anyone :)

‎‎‎‎‎‎
‎

https://www.veed.io/view/74f39d5e-953b-420e-8b4d-6f5ed05a2913

Comment: Okay, that's strange... all settings seem to be correct as far as I can tell from that video...

Comment: Hmm okay... ty for taking the time tho :)

Can anyone other maybe help ... thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this happening generally or just in a special file?

Comment: I made a test file to check this and its happening in ALL of my files when i try to texture paint. The same problem ... even if i just wanna paint a simple cube